# TeXShop - XeLaTeX: How to include tamil scripts?

Tags: xetex, fontspec, tamil

I am using TeXShop - XeLaTeX on a MacBook Pro with Mountain Lion. I used the following:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\begin{document}

அ

\end{document}
```

I got an error:

```
Undefined control sequence \UTF ...
```

Could anyone give some suggestions so that I can use Tamil unicode fonts as part of my LaTeX file.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`). Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: In a current TeX-System you example does not give an error. It doesn't give the glyph either as the font doesn't contain it, you will have to switch to another font e.g. with `{\fontspec{Arial Unicode MS}அ}`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare a font that covers Tamil; for instance on my machine I have InaiMathi; then `polyglossia` can take care of some aspects of Tamil.

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\tamilfont{InaiMathi}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{tamil}

\begin{document}

அ

தமிழ்

\end{document}
```

[image]

The file must be saved as UTF-8 and processed with XeLaTeX.

Comment: When I did the above, I got these error messages in the log:

Comment: Sorry for the previous goof up. When I did as egret (also Ulrich Fisher) suggested, I got the same error message. 1st line of the log: This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-0.9998 (TeX Live 2012) (format=xelatex 2012.6.30)